# Fix SELinux labels after restoring /data on CM 12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, selinux, rsync

I restored an automatic backup on Cyanogenmod 12.1 created with rsync of my /data partition, but now SELinux is denying apps access to their data.

Disabling SELinux "fixes" this problem, but can I repair the SELinux labels once after restoring and keep SELinux enforced?

Comment: I've never tried this. Android provide tools to change SELinux context for a file. See http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_1#SELinux_Commands and this for understanding: http://www.all-things-android.com/content/understanding-se-android-policy-files